# Radius of Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Find the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2z^n$$

(If it matters, $z$ is a complex variable.)

My attempt:

The radius of convergence is

\begin{align*}
R&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Bigl\lvert\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\Bigl\lvert\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Bigl\lvert\dfrac{n^2z^n}{(n+1)^2z^{n+1}}\Bigl\lvert\\
&= \dfrac{1}{z}
\end{align*}

I was under the impression that the radius of convergence was supposed to be a number, so am I doing something wrong, or is this correct?

Comment: The $a_n$ is the thing in front of the $z^n$ and it doesn't contain the $z_n$.

Comment: @xavierm02 Ah, I completely forgot about that! If you put your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the general result:

> If $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = r$ exists, and $r<1$ then $\sum |a_n|$ converges,
>   and if $r>1$  $\sum |a_n|$ diverges.

Here,
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to z
$$and then

- if $|z|<1$ there is convergence, and then $R\ge 1$
- if $|z|>1$ there is divergence, and then $R\le 1$

hence the radius $R= 1$